# Connecting AWS MySQL database as a linked server in SQL Server 2012

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I've set up a System DSN to the MySQL database and the connection is okay when I test it.  When I set up a linked server using that DSN it connects and I can see the catalog and tables but when I try to query it, I get an error that says "contains no columns that can be selected or the current user does not have permissions on that object".  When I use the same settings to connect through MySQL Workbench it works and I can query the data. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide accurate details on your problem, along with code examples or queries examples.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the service account has permissions.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  The service account is an sa in SQL Server and the login credentials I use for the linked server work in MySQL Workbench so I think they're okay.